# is there any way to show wommerce variation like mix and match products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to show my woocommerce website's variable product front end should show like this (kindly check image). Is there any way to do? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMdVP.jpg)

I tried this function but it's not working

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_variation_title_image');
function display_variation_title_image( $term_name ) {
global $wp_query;

```
$variation_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
$attachment_id = $variation->get_image_id();
$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' );

if ( $image_src ) {
    $term_name .= '<img src="' . $image_src[0] . '" alt="' . $term_name . '" />';
}

return $term_name;
```

}
`

Comment: That's not a variable product, but a bundle product. You can achieve that with appropriate plugins, e.g. https://woocommerce.com/de-de/products/product-bundles

Comment: I actually wanted to show variations like this and I developed a custom plugin for this feature. Thank you so much for replying.